# Use of Matlab normxcorr2 () template matching error occurs

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pattern-matching, computer-vision

I want to make the template matching, using the Matlab normxcorr2 (),
Results such as pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc66d.jpg

Left a successful match, the right failed,
Here is the code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNajn.jpg

I can not find where the problem
Please help me: (

Comment: Why does it fail? What is the error? Please be elaborate and as clear as possible with your question.

Comment: @Zaphod Two pictures are selected template red blocks on the right shoulder,While the left image can be correctly matched to the corresponding position, but on the right has failed,Whether I'm doing a variety of cutting, or choose a different block,Match result is a failure :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalised cross-correlation effectively creates a metric for each pixel that accounts for it's variation from the mean, normalised by a factor of the standard deviation over the entire image. In this case, your query patch is an almost uniform red region, which means there is almost no variance in the pixels. This is why it finds the floor, where again there is little or no variance. For template matching with normalised cross-correlation, you need some texture on the template. For your current problem, you may be better off just detecting a red blob using an exhaustive search.

Comment: I have tried using other template matching,
And whether you use pure color templates
Or non-pure color templates, results have failed: (


like this picture:http://imgur.com/SjHjdHJ

Comment: Getting scale and rotation invariance is a whole other matter, to be honest. You'll need to find some way to carry out scale- and rotation-invariant template matching for the example you've shown here. Basic methods just won't do.